# Associative array not working properly in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I want to pass the associative array value on API request.

I am passing following values on it.

```
    var myArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
    for answer in answeredQuestions{
        for pushingValue in answer.answers{
            if pushingValue.getIsChecked(){
              let dict  = ["questionID":"\(answer.id)" as AnyObject,
                           "answerID":"\(pushingValue.id)" as AnyObject]
              myArray.append(dict)
            }
        }
    }
```

And append the user id like below:

```
    func answerToTheQuestion(answer:[Any]){
  
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "userID" : UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userID")!,
            
            "data": answer
        ]
    }
```

When i try to return this same value from api, I am getting this stuff in wrong way. Like below.

Advise me is there any problem,

```
"<pre>Array\n(\n    
[data] => Array\n 
(\n 
[0] => Array\n (\n  [answerID] => 1\n )\n\n            
[1] => Array\n (\n  [questionID] => 1\n )\n\n       
[2] => Array\n (\n  [answerID] => 3\n )\n\n            
[3] => Array\n (\n  [questionID] => 2\n )\n\n       
)\n\n    [userID] => 28\n)\n"
```

Is there any problem in it? Correct me ?

When i pass it on Rest Client, I am getting the response in following way.

```
 <pre>Array
 (
  [userID] => 28
  [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [questionID] => 1
                [answerID] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [questionID] => 2
                [answerID] => 3
            )

    )

 )
```

Rest client response structure is perfect. that is i want. But when i try to use it app using Alamofire, I am getting wrong format like i mentioned before.

Comment: First the correct type for dictionary in Swift since Swift 3 is `[String:Any]` instead of `[String:AnyObject]`. Btw if your dictionary values are always string declare it as `[String: String]`. Second why are you using an array of Any `[Any]`?

Comment: [Any] means , some times it will come as String , some time it will come as array. so, i mentioned it as [Any].